# After installing of windows hosting bundle, still getting HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure error in .Net core 1.1.0

Tags: .net-core

I am getting `HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure` error while running the application. When I execute `dotnet C:\app.dll` on command line, it gives me below message

[image]

I installed windows hosting package `1.0.4-1.1.1` and `1.0.5-1.1.2` but no luck. It is still complaining the same.

Can anyone please help me out. I already spent my whole day trying to fix this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed correct .net core version? Basically issue above that the server unable to detect that .net core has been installed on the server. Check your web.config file again, maybe this post http://dotnet4europeanhosting.hostforlife.eu/post/European-ASPNET-Core-Hosting-HostForLIFEeu-How-to-Fix-Error-5025-Process-Failure-in-ASPNET-Core.aspx can help you.